# Get current video duration from CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, avfoundation, cmsamplebufferref

How can I get current recorded video duration from CMSampleBufferRef in delegate method

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
```

Please guide with sample code

Answer (score -1):

The details which you need is in the video meta data. To get the video meta data you may need to convert your `CMSampleBuffer` to `CVPixelBuffer`.

`CMSampleBuffer` is a Core Foundation-style opaque type; an instance contains the sample buffer for a frame of video data.
`CVPixelBuffer` is core video pixels from the Sample Buffer.

You can get the Pixel buffer from sample buffer by using the below `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer:`

`CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(<#A CMSampleBuffer#>);`

Once you got the pixel buffer you can get the video meta datas like timing and format informations.

To get timing informations use `CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp` and `CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp` respectively.

For more info read [Representations of Media](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/06_MediaRepresentations.html)

Comment: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp requires a CMSampleBuffer (not a CVPixelBuffer)